# Tslint to ESLint Migration Error : unknown option '--remove-tslint-if-no-more-tslint-targets'

Tags: angular, eslint, tslint, prettier-eslint

I am using the below option to convert from TSLint to ESLint on Angular 11 and getting the below error

```
ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:convert-tslint-to-eslint --remove-tslint-if-no-more-tslint-targets

unknown option '--remove-tslint-if-no-more-tslint-targets'
```

I have researched for few hours and I couldn't fix it , anyone can help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You should not update it all by hand. First update angular to version 12, see https://update.angular.io/?v=11.0-12.0. Then use the guide at https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint. Also covers prettier.